# jquery - clicking outside of div

Tags: jquery

Right now, I just have something that slides open if hovered over, and slides closed if the mouse leaves. I'd like if I could keep it open until someone clicks outside of it.

Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First just assign a `mouseenter` event so that it opens when you hover:

```
$('#someDiv').mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).codeToOpenIt
});
```

Then place a click event on the document to close it when the user clicks anywhere.

```
$(document).click(function() {
    $('#someDiv').codeToCloseIt
});
```

The reason this works is that events bubble from the element that was clicked, up to the root. So placing a `click()` event on the `document` will catch all clicks on the page, and will close your element.

Note that any elements on the page that have a click that does:

```
return false;
```

or

```
event.stopPropagation();
```

will cause the bubbling to halt, preventing the handler on the document from firing.

Comment: I'd add that you may not want to close the div if someone clicks inside that div, which the code above will do.  To prevent this, add a click handler to the div itself that stops propagation (`event.stopPropagation()`) so that the document's click handler won't be reached.

Comment: Also, if the element has focus, and you want you can add keystroke events - like make it close if someone hits ESC key for instance.